# How to stop tinymce from adding height and width to image src?

Tags: facebook, tinymce, umbraco7

We are using Umbraco as the CMS for our website. Umbraco uses tinymce as a rich text editor for populating rich content. The issue is that whenever we add images via the media picker on tinymce the image is inserted with a width and height parameters padded to src tag. The example is below:

```
<img style="width: 500px; margin: 0px auto; max-width: 100%;" src="/media/9693/whatever.jpg?width=500&amp;height=333.33333333333337" alt="Whatever" height="" title="Whatever">
```

This creates problem when we try to add the page url (with this image) on a Facebook status update. The images with the padded width and height to src tag doesn't show up in the list of images Facebook generates.

What do I need to do so that tinymce doesn't add the "?width=500&height=333.33333333333337" part to the image src?

Comment: From looking at an Umbraco demo site (and working with TinyMCE regularly) I believe that the code you are wanting to change is part of Umbraco and not TinyMCE itself.  The default TinyMCE image plugin does not add attributes to the image url (the ?width=xxx&height=xxx as you show in your example).  I suspect that the Umbraco media manager is inserting that HTML and it is what you would need to change.

Comment: You are right. This looks like a Umbraco media picker issue. TinyMCE in itself works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Developer section, under Data Types, choose your Rich Text Editor data type and set the `Maximum size for inserted images` to `0`.

[image]